# Background image cut off outside of item. How can I make it show?

Tags: css, html-lists, background-image

I have a background image that is positioned correctly on the background of a ul li item.

I want to position it just off the edge of the lime container, however when I do position it correctly it cuts off any part of the image not inside the container.

How can I make it show even if it is outside the container, and not cut off like this?

[image]

**Desired result**

[image]

**CSS**

```
body ul#main_navigation li li:hover > a, body ul#main_navigation li li.over > a
{
     background-image:url(/images/nav_arrow_right.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position: 197px 12px;
     background-color: #0F0;
     color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: You can't make a background image show off the edge of it's container, it wouldn't be a background image then! You'll need to restructure your markup

Comment: move your image `arrow` to `div of cardrona` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `background-image` protrude from any element. You could use a `span` attached to the element, or attach the background image to the element next to it, giving the illusion that it is part of the original element.

Personally I would use a `span` with a background image inside the element positioned to sit outside of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can have an image that breaks the bounds of the container. You could try making the li slightly wider, to accomodate the arrow image and then move the child element to the left.

Or you could just put the arrow as a background on the child element.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you put this image as background of the first list item of the sublist?